# Rails not running the gem in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm

I'm running Rails 3.2.1 & Ruby 1.9.2-p290 within an RVM environment

Within my dev folder, I have a number of different Rails apps, all running the above, but I haven't created separate gemsets

I created a new app with its own gemfile, ran bundle install etc and all was ok till I went back the the main app I was working on originally

When I now do a rake routes I get the error

```
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.2. Using bundle exec     may solve this.
```

I think I know how to get back on track, but here's what I don't understand:

When I look at the .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems folder, I can see a folder for each of the gems for rake-0.8.7, rake-0.9.2.2, rake-10.0.2, rake-10.0.3

So I have a version of rake 10.0.2 installed, my main app gemfile.lock calls for rake(10.0.2) and when I run bundle exec rake routes it does actually work (presumeably running 10.0.2?), but when I run a straight rake routes, Rails seems to want to run a different version of Rake that its not being asked to.

So my question is how do I know which version of an installed Gem is actually being run, given that calling for a particular version of an installed Gem seems not to do as you'd expect?

(separately, I guess that if I'm developing different apps within the same RVM space, I should probably be creating separate gemsets for each app?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this problem is fixed in rubygems 2.0 - Gemfile can be respected for loading any executable gem.

as for your problem RVM comes with my gem installed `rubygems-bundler` and it should automatically resolve dependencies if possible - it would fallback to your problem if proper version is not installed, there is a ticket to change the situation to raise an exception in that case - https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler/issues/37

basically - make sure you run `bundle install` before doing anything in the project, and `rubygems-bundler` will ensure proper versions of gems are ran.

Comment: my problem is that rake 10.0.2 IS installed, but that a separate Rails app has caused 10.0.3 to be installed as well, so even after running bundle install in my original app, I still get the error above. The relevant line from running gem list is: rake (10.0.3, 10.0.2, 0.9.2.2 ruby, 0.8.7). It seems, as Yves Senn says below that Rails runs the latest version of a gem regardless of what's in the Gemfile?

Comment: run: `gem install rubygems-bundler; gem regenerate_binstubs`. as explained above it should take care of selecting proper version of rake.

Comment: ah, I didn't realise that you had to install rubygems-bundler separately. That makes sense, thanks

Comment: rvm does install rubygems-bundler by default, you could have it missing if ruby was compiled in very old rvm, otherwise it could be a bug and should be reported for investigation

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you have multiple versions of the same gem installed, the binary you will execute `rake` is always the latest version. If your application then depends on an older version of that gem, it can't activate it, since the newer version is already loaded.

There are three solutions:

1. use `bundle exec rake` this will always use the version from your Gemfile
2. use bundler binstubs: `bundle --binstubs`. This creates a `./bin` folder in your project. You can now access the binaries for the specified gem versions from your Gemfile. You can call rake with `./bin/rake`
3. uninstall the newer version so that the binary points to the one in your Gemfile

**EDIT:** As you mentioned you can also create separate gemsets to postpone the problem. There will be times though when you update a gem on a branch and then switch that you will get the error nonetheless.